# Force ticks to be perpendicular to axis in ternary plot

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I understand that for most ppl the ticks in ternary are ok, but I need them to be perpendicular to the axis. The axis in ternary plot are aslope, i want them to be in 90 degrees with the axis.See my poor art:

[image: Perpendicular ticks]

Poor art v2:

[image: zoom on perpendicular ticks]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{verdeclaro}{RGB}{178,223,138}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
ternary limits relative=false,
xlabel= Solid, 
xlabel style={at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},anchor=south},
ylabel= Liquid, 
ylabel style={at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},anchor=north east},
zlabel= Gas,
zlabel style={at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},anchor=north west},
minor tick num=1,
xtick align=inside,
ytick align=inside,
ztick align=inside,
grid=none,
xticklabels={,,},
yticklabels={,,},
zticklabels={,,},
area style,
axis line style={thick},
clip=false,
disabledatascaling,
]

\addplot3[fill=verdeclaro, dashed,thin] table {
0.6 0 0.4
0 1 0.4 
0 0 1
};
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please check your text and the pictures. It is not clear, what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Taking a brief look at [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) manual not only I did not find such a feature for tweaking with ternary plots ticks nor I found one single plot example where the ticks are like you suggest, neither did Images of ternary plots in a Google search. This makes me believe that the ticks are _not supposed_ to be ortogonal to the axis.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Good point, that's because i'm not doing a exact ternary it's more like a illustrative diagram. But the tick angle is debatable:
http://labvirtual.eq.uc.pt/siteJoomla/images/stories/llefund11.png

https://sites.google.com/site/extraccionliquidoliquidoupiig/_/rsrc/1432548698313/introduccion-a-las-operaciones-unitarias/f3.png?height=273&width=320

http://www.scielo.br/img/revistas/qn/v36n9/a11fig05.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if it is an ilustrative diagram, it does not really need the ternary plot. You could just use `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,decoration={ticks, pre length=2.5mm, segment length=5mm, post length=2.5mm, amplitude=2pt}]
\def\A{Liquid} \def\B{Gas}
\def\C{Solid}
\coordinate [label=left:\A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:\B] (B) at (50mm,0);
\node [name path=D] at (A) [circle through=(B)] {};
\node [name path=E] at (B) [circle through=(A)] {};
\path [name intersections={of=D and E,by={[label=above:\C]C}}];
\draw (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
\draw[decorate] (A) -- (C);
\draw[decorate] (C) -- (B);
\draw[decorate] (B) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation result]

Unfortunately you have to calculate the `segment lenght` Parameter in order for the ticks to be properly positioned (there is an automated way to do this I'm sure but I got lazy):

```
segment length = (veclength( (A)-(B) ) - (pre length+post length) )/ (number of ticks-1)
```

In this case was `(50-5)/9=5`